# Google+ Sign-In for server-side apps

Tags: javascript, php, google-api-php-client

Was going through the google tutorial page for implementing "Google+ Sign-In" for server-side apps.While proceeding in the tutorial ,I am stucked in Step 2 that says : Create an anti-request forgery state token .Below is the link for the tutorial :

```
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow
```

The tutorial says,I need to create the "unique session token" using below code.However I am wondering where do I need to place this code. In my index.html (which contains the sign in button) file ?? or something else.

```
  $state = md5(rand());
  $app['session']->set('state', $state);
  // Set the client ID, token state, and application name in the HTML while
  // serving it.
  return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
  'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
  'STATE' => $state,
  'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
  ));
```

Comment: Without the rest of your code, it's hard to give better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The CLIENT_ID, STATE, and APPLICATION_NAME go on every page that has the javascript for the sign-in button.

The STATE must be unique per session and must be consistent within a session, which is why it's generated using the hash of some random data and saved throughout the session.

Comment: if you go to the https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow tutorial it explains what this code is all about. but i have the same question, it doesn't say where to put the code. and it also doesn't specify how to refer to the api library which you have to download which has also been deprecated so there doesnt seem to be a current tutorial that i can understand?